# Not able to create the specific column in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl

I'm facing following issue in a Postgres database. 
I have table kart_user, I'm not able to create the column as user 
I'm getting following error.

```
syntax error at or near "user"
```

I can create other column as users,usersss... 
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: though i'm not familiar with psql I'd assume that user is the keyword for the currently logged in user. Either look for another name for that column or try to escape it. In mysql it youd be done by enclosing user with ``, in MSSQL with [ ] and I'm pretty sure there is a similiar way in psql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`user` is a reserved word, and therefore needs to be quoted:

```
create table kart_user
(
  id integer not null primary key,
  "user"  varchar(20)
);
```

But in general you should avoid quoted identifiers and find a different name for the column.

More details about the syntax of identifiers in the manual: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

A full list of keywords can also be found in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html

---

Once you have defined a quoted identifier you have to ***always*** quote the column name:

```
insert into kart_user (user) values ('Arthur');
```

Comment: How i can insert the data to "user"

Comment: insert into tablename (user) values("jhone") is failed

Comment: @AbdulRazak: that is all explained in the manual, but see my edit. Note that `"` is **only** used for identifiers. String constants are enclosed in with single quotes `'` in SQL. Again this is nicely explained in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS